# How to convert numeric value into formatted string in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array which have numeric value which starts with 0 like 05501. But when i m converting array into CSV file using array_chunk function, the value which starts with 0 is saving without 0 for e.g. 5501 which should be like 05501.

```
$rows = array_chunk($finaldata, $column);
print_r($rows);
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
foreach ($rows as $value) {
fputcsv($file,$value);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: You can use `str_pad` with `STR_PAD_LEFT` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This code ...

```
$file = fopen('result.csv', 'w');

$array = ['00001', '00002', '00003', '00004'];

foreach (array_chunk($array, 2) as $items)
{
    fputcsv($file, $items);
}

fclose($file);
```

... gives this result:

```
00001,00002
00003,00004
```

Are you sure that you open your result file in a text editor? You know, Excel cut leading zeros automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rows = array_chunk($finaldata, $column);
print_r($rows);

$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

foreach ($rows as $value) {
  $value = implode(",", $value);
  fputcsv($file, $value);
}

fclose($file);
```